# Farseer Player Movement and Collision

Tags: xna, c#, collision-detection, movement, farseer-physics-engine

*I have added a video link for any one who whats to see what the problems are by watching the game.*

I am trying to create a player movement system and there are small problems that I am running into.

I want to find the most accurate way of knowing if player is colliding with another object. I tried using `if (Player.Body.LinearVelocity.Y == 0.0f)` then player is not jumping and on ground. But if I add force to the X axis the y will fluctuate.   I also tried to use OnCollision but am confused on how to use it.

1. What is the best way to know if the player is colliding with the ground and can jump?
2. The player slides across the ground like it's ice how do i fix this problem? How would I make it into quick and sudden stops with little sliding.
3. Lets say I had a one color texture, and I wanted to use it on a rectangle and a circle but could not bother to make 2 textures and just want to do it in the coding. How could I make this texture go from a rectangle to any shape I want?
4. If OnCollision is the best way for me to detected where the player is hit (left, right, top, or bottom) and then use for the best and quickest collision test, were can I learn how to use this thing properly?
5. [Here is the Video.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M7qIyJg4xV0&feature=youtu.be)
6. How do you delete an object, I got the texture to go but not the object itself. The objects are spawned in and then stored on a list. How do you remove them from the list?
7. How come the player on the top left is more clearer then the player being controlled?

Comment: I recognize my tutorial :D. But anyways you have a lot of separate questions. Which is not a good fit for the Q&A format here. Please ask only one question per post (and best not post them all at once ;). As for the jumping problem. Why not just check the distance between the player and the last object he collide with? (Which you can get via OnCollision).

Comment: I understand were your coming from. I only did this as a list to see who could answer what, I saw the repercussions of having many answers correct for different question. I did this thinking that posting 6 questions in one day would look like I just wanted to earn points I can give all of these there own post if that I what it will take.

Comment: @RoyT. Is there some way of learning how to use this OnCollision, by some type of tutorial or website? I said that I did not understand it but am willing to learn anything to help create my game.

Comment: This forum post explains it pretty well: https://farseerphysics.codeplex.com/discussions/283336

Comment: I have looked over the forum post I was trying to understand but am still a little confused. I am sorry that I am being thick headed. [Here is my own post](https://farseerphysics.codeplex.com/discussions/535641).